# How to suppress the numbers and small signs when drawing axes using tkzAxeXY in tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-euclide

How to suppress the numbers and small signs when drawing axes using tkzAxeXY in tkz-euclide?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=3]
\tkzAxeXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In other words, instead of the output of the above file, to have the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\tkzDrawXY` instead of `\tkzAxeXY` to suppress the labels, use `\tkzSetUpAxis[ticka=0pt, tickb=0pt]` to suppress the ticks.

See the [`tkz-base` manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-base/doc/tkz-base-screen.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=3]
\tkzSetUpAxis[ticka=0pt, tickb=0pt]
\tkzDrawXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]